# How to hide thumbnail bar in QLPreviewcontroller document preview

Tags: objective-c, ios10, qlpreviewcontroller

I need to hide the thumbnail bar on double tapping the document preview. But if I add the `QLPreviewcontroller` as a subview, the double tapping is not working and the thumbnail bar is not hidden. I need to do this because the bar is hiding a right side part of the document. Please suggest me some way how to handle this.

If I present it as a `viewcontroller` I don't face any issue. But am not able to add a toolbar or edit the `navbar` of `QLPreviewcontroller` .

I need to also add a customized `Toolbar` to this `viewcontroller`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it, same issue, in fact generally as soon as you add a view from an another view controller inside a master view controller, you need to declare the child view controller as child :

```
[self addChildViewController:quicklookVC];
[quicklookVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

then now tap to hide / show option bar and thumbnail preview is working